# The package product 'ComposableArchitecture' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

Got this error:

> The package product 'ComposableArchitecture' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0

My iPad has iOS 15.1.

How can I adjust Package.swift?

```json
// swift-tools-version: 5.7

import PackageDescription

extension Target.Dependency {
    // app features
    static var appAdd: Self { "AppAdd" }
    static var appConfigure: Self { "AppConfigure" }
    static var appDetails: Self { "AppDetails" }
    static var appEnvironment: Self { "AppEnvironment" }
    static var appBuilds: Self { "AppBuilds" }
    static var appLogs: Self { "AppLogs" }
    static var appMetric: Self { "AppMetric" }
    static var appMetrics: Self { "AppMetrics" }
    static var cardView: Self { "CardView" }
    static var sidebar: Self { "Sidebar" }
    static var teamAdd: Self { "TeamAdd" }
    static var teamConfigure: Self { "TeamConfigure" }
    static var teams: Self { "Teams" }
    static var teamViewer: Self { "TeamViewer" }
    static var toolbar: Self { "Toolbar" }
    
    // dependencies
    static var cloudAPIClient: Self { "CloudAPIClient" }
    static var cloudAPITokenClient: Self { "CloudAPITokenClient" }
    static var httpClient: Self { "HTTPClient" }
    static var keychainClient: Self { "KeychainClient" }
    
    static var composableArchitecture: Self {
        .product(name: "ComposableArchitecture", package: "swift-composable-architecture")
    }
    
    static var dependencies: Self {
        .product(name: "Dependencies", package: "swift-composable-architecture")
    }
    
    static var cloudAPIDTOs: Self {
        .product(name: "CloudAPIDTOs", package: "CloudAPIDTOs")
    }
    
    static var jwtKit: Self {
        .product(name: "JWTKit", package: "jwt-kit")
    }
}

let package = Package(
    name: "ResponsiveCloud",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v13), .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "AppFeature", targets: ["AppFeature"]),

        // app features
        .library(name: "AppAdd", targets: ["AppAdd"]),
        .library(name: "AppConfigure", targets: ["AppConfigure"]),
        .library(name: "AppDetails", targets: ["AppDetails"]),
        .library(name: "AppEnvironment", targets: ["AppEnvironment"]),
        .library(name: "AppLogs", targets: ["AppLogs"]),
        .library(name: "AppMetric", targets: ["AppMetric"]),
        .library(name: "AppMetrics", targets: ["AppMetrics"]),
        .library(name: "CardView", targets: ["CardView"]),
        .library(name: "Menu", targets: ["Menu"]),
        .library(name: "Sidebar", targets: ["Sidebar"]),
        .library(name: "TeamAdd", targets: ["TeamAdd"]),
        .library(name: "TeamConfigure", targets: ["TeamConfigure"]),
        .library(name: "Teams", targets: ["Teams"]),
        .library(name: "TeamViewer", targets: ["TeamViewer"]),
        .library(name: "Toolbar", targets: ["Toolbar"]),
        
        // dependencies
        .library(name: "CloudAPIClient", targets: ["CloudAPIClient"]),
        .library(name: "CloudAPIClientLive", targets: ["CloudAPIClientLive"]),
        .library(name: "CloudAPITokenClient", targets: ["CloudAPITokenClient"]),
        .library(name: "CloudAPITokenClientLive", targets: ["CloudAPITokenClientLive"]),
        .library(name: "HTTPClient", targets: ["HTTPClient"]),
        .library(name: "HTTPClientLive", targets: ["HTTPClientLive"]),
        .library(name: "KeychainClient", targets: ["KeychainClient"]),
        .library(name: "KeychainClientLive", targets: ["KeychainClientLive"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(path: "../CloudAPIDTOs"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture.git", from: "0.45.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt-kit", from: "4.7.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "AppFeature", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .teams, .cloudAPIDTOs, .cloudAPITokenClient, .teamViewer, .appDetails, .cloudAPIClient, .appMetrics, .appLogs, .appBuilds, .appEnvironment, .appConfigure, .sidebar, .toolbar]),
        
        // app features
        .target(name: "AppAdd", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture]),
        .target(name: "AppConfigure", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture]),
        .target(name: "AppDetails", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .appMetrics, .appLogs, .appBuilds, .appEnvironment, .appConfigure, .cloudAPIClient, .cardView]),
        .target(name: "AppEnvironment", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture]),
        .target(name: "AppMetric", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .cardView]),
        .target(name: "AppBuilds", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .cardView]),
        .target(name: "AppMetrics", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .appMetric, .cloudAPIDTOs, .cloudAPIClient]),
        .target(name: "AppLogs", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .cardView, .cloudAPIClient]),
        .target(name: "CardView"),
        .target(name: "Menu", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture]),
        .target(name: "Sidebar", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .appAdd]),
        .target(name: "TeamAdd", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .cloudAPIClient, .appAdd]),
        .target(name: "TeamConfigure", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture]),
        .target(name: "Teams", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .teamViewer, .teamAdd, .cloudAPIDTOs, .cloudAPIClient, .appDetails, .appAdd, .sidebar, .toolbar    ]),
        .target(name: "TeamViewer", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .sidebar, .toolbar, .cloudAPIClient, .appDetails]),
        .target(name: "Toolbar", dependencies: [.composableArchitecture, .teamAdd, .cloudAPITokenClient]),
        
        // dependencies
        .target(name: "CloudAPIClient", dependencies: [.dependencies, .cloudAPIDTOs]),
        .target(name: "CloudAPIClientLive", dependencies: [.dependencies, .cloudAPIDTOs, .cloudAPITokenClient, .cloudAPIClient, .httpClient]),
        .target(name: "CloudAPITokenClient", dependencies: [.dependencies, .keychainClient, .jwtKit]),
        .target(name: "CloudAPITokenClientLive", dependencies: [.dependencies, .cloudAPITokenClient]),
        .target(name: "HTTPClient", dependencies: [.dependencies]),
        .target(name: "HTTPClientLive", dependencies: [.dependencies, .httpClient]),
        .target(name: "KeychainClient", dependencies: [.dependencies]),
        .target(name: "KeychainClientLive", dependencies: [.dependencies, .keychainClient]),
        
        // tests
        .testTarget(name: "ResponsiveCloudAppTests", dependencies: ["AppFeature", .cloudAPIClient, "CloudAPIClientLive", .jwtKit]),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Does your Xcode project have a minimal target of iOS 13?

Comment: Are you trying to build this package directly? Or are you trying to build another project which depends on this package? Are you trying to build from command line or Xcode?